# How to drop all constraints (CHECK, PRIMARY, FOREIGN, UNIQUE..) using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to drop all constraints (CHECK, PRIMARY, FOREIGN, UNIQUE,...) using SQL Server 2008? I tried this code, but it drops only foreign key constraints:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: but i need all key include primary,unique also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you could update your `SQL` Script with below :

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'';
SELECT @sql+=N'
ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id))+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(name)+';'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT';
PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Use `sys.objects` which will give you all constraints by filtering `WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'`